# appcenter Sending logs groupName=group_core id=XXX failed

Tags: visual-studio-app-center, httpexception

I am developing a project in Android studio.

In my Service component, I wrote this:

```
AppCenter.start(application, "XXX",
                    Analytics::class.java, Crashes::class.java)
```

after I ran the app, log show this:

```
2021-08-21 00:00:05.191 6505-9493/com.asus.alwayson E/AppCenter: Sending logs groupName=group_core id=XXX failed
    com.microsoft.appcenter.http.HttpException: 400 - {"status":"NoValidLogsFoundInLogContainer","validDiagnosticsIds":[],"throttledDiagnosticsIds":[],"correlationId":"XXX"}
        at com.microsoft.appcenter.http.DefaultHttpClientCallTask.doHttpCall(DefaultHttpClientCallTask.java:265)
        at com.microsoft.appcenter.http.DefaultHttpClientCallTask.doInBackground(DefaultHttpClientCallTask.java:279)
        at com.microsoft.appcenter.http.DefaultHttpClientCallTask.doInBackground(DefaultHttpClientCallTask.java:48)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$3.call(AsyncTask.java:394)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:923)
```

Is there any way to solve it?

Comment: I found that it may be caused by a time issue.
AppCenter will Discarded a log older than 25 days or more than 3 in the future.
I change device time, this problem is solved.

Comment: Please make sure that you use the correct App Center app_secret.